# Is it possible to undelete an answer which is deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I had a Q&A [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622233/how-to-change-the-timeout-between-sudo-sessions) which was deleted by a moderator because the source was not included. I have now added the source and edited the answer. Is it possible to undelete it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question exactly as it is asked: no. It is not possible to undelete an answer that has been deleted by a moderator.

It is possible to flag the answer for moderator intervention.

Comment: Thanks for this