# url redirected to askubuntu question when the meta part is removed

Tags: discussion, bug

I had a [question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13980/is-it-possible-to-undelete-an-answer-which-is-deleted-by-a-moderator) on askubuntu meta.

```
https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13980/is-it-possible-to-undelete-an-answer-which-is-deleted-by-a-moderator
```

When I deleted the `https://meta.` part and reloaded the url it redirected me to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6646/how-to-enable-hp-pavilion-tx1000-touch-screen/13980#13980) url

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/6646/how-to-enable-hp-pavilion-tx1000-touch-screen/13980#13980
```

Possibly a bug?

Answer (score 7):

I assume that when you wrote "Stack Overflow", you meant "Ask Ubuntu Meta".

Ask Ubuntu (http://askubuntu.com) and Ask Ubuntu Meta (http://meta.askubuntu.com) are two completely different websites (though they are related). Because of this, each has its own set of questions and answers.

Here's what happened in your specific example: [the question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13980/is-it-possible-to-undelete-an-answer-which-is-deleted-by-a-moderator) has an ID of `13980` on Ask Ubuntu Meta. There is [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6646/how-to-enable-hp-pavilion-tx1000-touch-screen/13980#13980) on Ask Ubuntu that happens to have the same ID. When you attempt to load a page with the ID of the answer in place of the question ID in the URL, you are automatically redirected to the appropriate URL for the question.

tl;dr — this is not a bug.